# Encoding uploaded file name

Tags: php, encode

My current site allows user file uploads, so, to avoid collisions i need to encode stored file names in some way. But i'd like to be able to retrieve original file names for downloads. So, i'm trying to encode file name to be

- unique
- decodable

As of now, i've tried to use following code:

```
    $hash = $file->hashName();

    $fileName = base64_encode(json_encode([
        'hash' => $hash,
        'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName()
    ]));       
    return $fileName;
```

But `base64_encode` produces longer than 256 symbols strings, especially when file name is using unicode characters (like cyrillic). So, is there any other way to encode file names?

Comment: Don't you like to store original file names?

Comment: Can't you just store the original names in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would simpler to do mapping. For saving files on disk you pick some unique name. In database you keep ref about that uploaded file with original file name, and file name on disk and when someone wants to download that file you set original filename in Content-Disposition header.

```
header('Content-Disposition: filename="originalFilename.pdf"');
```